# Why does this gamma function equality hold?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

I am trying to understand a 'given' in Titchmarsh's third proof of the functional equation for Riemann's zeta function (E. C. Titchmarsh (1986). The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-function (2nd ed.). Oxford: Oxford Science Publications. Section 2.4, pp. 21-22, also quoted on the Wikipedia page for the zeta function [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Riemann%27s_functional_equation)). The proof begins with the observation that for $\Re(s)>0$

$$\int_0^{\infty } x^{\frac{1}{2}s-1} e^{-n^2  \pi  x} \, dx = \frac{\Gamma  \left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}{n^s \pi ^{s/2}}$$

I realise it probably only requires basic algebra, but I don't understand how one gets to this statement from the definition of the gamma function

$$\Gamma (s) = \int_0^{\infty } x^{s-1} e^{-x} \, dx, \Re(s)>0$$

I reason as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}
\Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2}\right) &= \int_0^{\infty } x^{\frac{1}{2}s-1} e^{-x} \, dx
\\
\\ \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}{n^s \pi^{s/2}} &= \frac{1}{n^s \pi ^{s/2}} \int_0^{\infty } x^{\frac{1}{2}s-1} e^{-x} \, dx
\\
\\ &= \int_0^{\infty } x^{\frac{1}{2}s-1} \frac{e^{-x}}{n^s \pi ^{s/2}} \, dx
\end{aligned}$$

with the last step being justified because the integral is over $x$ and $\frac{1}{n^s \pi ^{s/2}}$ is therefore effectively a constant in relation to it.

But then I get lost, because it's obvious that $ n^{-s} \pi^{-s/2} e^{-x} \neq e^{-n^2  \pi  x}$.

Could someone explain how the integral expression above for $\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{s}{2}\right)}{n^s \pi^{s/2}}$ is derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=n^2 \pi x$, so the integral becomes

$$ \int_0^\infty dx \ x^{-1+s/2} e^{-n^2 \pi x} = \int_0^\infty \frac{du}{n^2 \pi} \left( \frac{u}{n^2\pi} \right)^{-1+s/2} e^{-u}=\frac{1}{(n^2\pi)^{s/2}} \int_0^\infty du \ u^{-1+s/2} e^{-u}$$

The integral on the right is $\Gamma(s/2)$, so we are left with

$$ \int_0^\infty dx \ x^{-1+s/2} e^{-n^2 \pi x} =\frac{1}{n^s \pi^{s/2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right) $$$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: Hi @Sal. Can you elaborate? I understand that $\left(\frac{u}{n^2 \pi} \right)^{\frac{s}{2}-1}\frac{ du}{n^2 \pi}$ resolves to $\frac{1}{\left(n^2 \pi \right)^{s/2}}u^{\frac{s}{2}-1} du$. But surely this leaves us with $e^{-x}=e^{- \frac{u}{n^2 \pi}}$? How do you obtain the term $e^{-u}$?

Comment: We first had $\exp(-n^2 \pi x)$, then with the substitution $u=n^2 \pi x$ we have $\exp(-u)$. I'm starting with the LHS of your first expression.

Comment: <<Lightbulb moment>> d'oh! Many thanks @Sal.